EM Wave propagation diagrams intuition/confusion

When I look for information about EM waves I see a lot of diagrams that look like this. But I find the interpretation of the x,y,z axis here a bit confusing.
I understand that there is an electric field that has a value at each point in space, and that value is a vector that describes a force that would be exerted on a charge.
So I see the red shaded area, is that (the length and direction of the arrow) telling me something about the "value" of the electric field at points in space along the y axis, or is it just telling me about the "force in the y direction" of a point along the x axis and this diagram tells me nothing about how the "value vectors" of the E field change if we were to drop a charge further into the y direction at a given x point?
In other words, if I know the value of x that I want to evaluate the field at, the length of the red arrow says "how hard" the E field is pushing in the y direction at that x point?
But if I was to pick an x point (assume y = 0) and then pick a point where y = 1 or 0.0001 or whatever but x is the same, then this diagram doesn't inherently suggest anything about how the vector direction would be different between the two points?

I've posted (a while ago) some visualizations in this answer that might help with building some intuition.


In other words, if I know the value of $x$ that I want to evaluate the field at, the length of the red arrow says "how hard" the $E$ field is pushing in the $y$ direction at that $x$ point?

Correct.

But if I was to pick an $x$ point (assume $y = 0$) and then pick a point where $y = 1$ or $0.0001$ or whatever but $x$ is the same, then this diagram doesn't inherently suggest anything about how the vector direction would be different between the two points?

Correct. But a diagram like this is usually associated with an infinite plane wave. The behaviour of such infinite plane waves is such that there is no $y$ or $z$ dependencies, only $x$ dependency. i.e. for a given $x$ value, the everywhere on that entire $yz$ plane will see the exact same $E$ field and same $B$ field.
Of course, this infinite plane wave is an additional assumption that is not yet apparent in this diagram. However, if it is not an infinite plane wave, this diagram ought to be changed; it would not have a uniform amplitude, for example.

So I see the red shaded area, is that telling me something about the "value" of the electric field at points in space along the $y$ axis,

Easy, that is not an area at all. We have no choice but to plot many arrows to show you what we mean, but that unfortunately gives the impression of an area. That is a wrong impression; both the author and the reader cannot help this.

or is it just telling me about the "force in the $y$ direction" of a point along the $x$ axis and this diagram tells me nothing about how the "value vectors" of the $E$ field change if we were to drop a charge further into the $y$ direction at a given $x$ point?

Correct; see my reply to the 2nd quotation above.

Ok, so if I take the picture I posted in the OP as an example it ONLY makes sense to evaluate this wave in 1 dimension  (i.e at an x position). If we had a wave that was not a plane wave (e.g x and y co-ordinates in the field), then to render a similar diagram, you would need the red and blue areas to look more like hills or something?

I'm not sure what you are trying to get at. As of infinite plane waves, the red arrows and the blue arrows make perfect sinusoidal waves. If the plane waves are not infinite, then the amplitude of these sinusoidal waves should decay. If it is not even a plane wave at all, then the shapes can be completely something else.

I mean, say there was some "fall off"/decay in the y direction so it wasn't a perfect plane wave. Then you would have to draw more of the red/blue shapes to represent that? I think I'm just trying to make sure I understand.. The red arrows represent a force at a point in a direction and not something "spreading out" in space. I suppose it makes more sense to represent it mathematically really. I think a better way to put it might be that a wave doesn't have an "area"?

I wouldn't put it out so cut-and-dried either. I mean, each wave lobe clearly has a nice and well-defined area; the integral of the sine's wave areas is a cosine and vice versa, as you definitely know. Decay just means that each lobe is less tall than the next one. As in, from $A\sin(kx)$ you change to $A e^{-\lambda x}\sin(kx)$ and see how that differs

Yes, the "area" of the red parts would decrease as we move along x in the Ae−λxsin(kx) case. But it doesn't represent an "area in space".. e.g if we took the OP picture (no damping) and placed a particle at an x/y point, only the x component would matter, and the arrow length tells us the force on it in y direction. It's NOT like "you placed the charge/particle outside of the y area, so the wave has no effect". At least that's my intuition assuming I understand correctly.
